# SimpleDateFormat Parses and Compares time incorrectly

Tags: java, time, compare, simpledateformat

When using the following SimpleDateFormat:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
```

Then I parse then compare 2 values: `12:19` and `11:40` like so:

```
val = format.parse("12:19").compareTo(format.parse("11:40"));
```

I get `val` to be **-1**, which seems wrong since 12hrs and 19mins is greater than 11hrs and 40mins

However when I change the first value to `19:19` and compare it again to `11:40` then `val` returns a value of **1** which seems to be correct.

Not sure why this is, I think i'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12:19 is interpreted as 00:19 because of "hh". You need "HH".

hh is 1-12 format.

HH is 0-23 format.

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that, I knew it was something small and stupid. Thanks!